# Cuando lanzo un error dentro del flujo de un Observable, pierdo la suscripción

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
this.ruleRepeatedValidate$.map((rule: ApiRule): ApiRulesOperation => {

   return (rules: ApiRule[]) => {

     let found: ApiRule = rules.find(t => t.rule === rule.rule);

     if (found !== undefined) {

       let exception: Error = {
         name: "Regla repetida",
         message: "No se puede repetir el nombre de la regla."
       };

       throw exception;
     }

     return rules;
   }
}).subscribe(this.update$);
```

Lo que hace es validar si el nombre de una regla(Nombre, IP Inicial, IP Final) ya existe previamente. En caso que exista lanzo un error.

Quien captura el error:

```
            this.rules$ = this.update$
            .scan((rules: ApiRule[], operation: ApiRulesOperation) => operation(rules), initialRules)
            .catch((exception: Error): Observable<ApiRule[]> => {
                console.log("Error capturado: ", exception);
                return Observable.just(initialRules);
            })
            .shareReplay(1);
```

Cuando se lanza el error, el ruleRepeatedValidate$:Subject pierde la suscripción a update$:BehaviorSubject.

He visto que existe [Retry](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retry.html) y [RetryWhen](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html) pero no se como usarlos para resolver el problema.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Saludos.

Comment: Qué versión de RxJs estás usando?

Comment: Estoy usando rxjs v4 [Codigo fuente](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)

Comment: Tienes algunas cosas raras en el código: creas un objeto de tipo Error y luego, en lugar de hacer algo con él, lanzas directamente la clase Error. ¿No debería ser `throw exception;`?

Comment: Si @PabloLozano es correcto, es como lo tengo, estaba haciendo pruebas y lo deje mal, ya lo he corregido.

Comment: Parece que mi problema es más de este tipo 
[El suscriptor no debe detenerse por error en observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986873/subscriber-should-not-stop-on-error-in-observable)

Comment: Estaba pensando en algo así, pero es que no terminaba de entender el código: no veo la relación entre el primer bloque de código y el segundo

Comment: @PabloLozano ahora muestro todo el servicio, con esto se aclara un poco mejor lo que intento hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Las suscripciones se cancelan siempre en caso de error. Puedes hacer dos cosas:

- Volver a suscribirte al observable tras capturar un error con `Observable.catch`.
- Usar el operador [`Observable.onErrorResumeNext`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/onerrorresumenext.md) para hacer que la subscripción automáticamente se renueve en caso de error:

  ```
  Observable.onErrorResumeNext(miObservable).subscribe(...)
  ```